# Implements turn left function in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Basically, I need to change the eye and up vectors correctly when pressing the left key (turning the view to right). My implementation is as follows but it does not seem to pass the tests. Anyone can help?

```
// Transforms the camera left around the "crystal ball" interface
void Transform::left(float degrees, vec3& eye, vec3& up) {
    // YOUR CODE FOR HW1 HERE
    eye = rotate(degrees, vec3(0, 1, 0)) * eye;
    up = rotate(degrees, vec3(0, 1, 0)) * up;
}
```

The rotation function takes two arguments degree and axis, and returns the rotation matrix which is a 3 by 3 matrix:

```
mat3 Transform::rotate(const float degrees, const vec3& axis) {
    // YOUR CODE FOR HW1 HERE

    mat3 rot, I(1.0);
    mat3 a_x;
    a_x[0][0] = 0;
    a_x[0][1] = -axis[2];
    a_x[0][2] = axis[1];
    a_x[1][0] = axis[2];
    a_x[1][1] = 0;
    a_x[1][2] = -axis[0];
    a_x[2][0] = -axis[1];
    a_x[2][1] = axis[0];
    a_x[2][2] = 0;
    float theta = degrees / 180 * pi;
    rot = I * cos(theta) + glm::outerProduct(axis, axis) *(1-cos(theta)) + a_x*sin(theta);
    return rot;
}
```

Comment: You are not providing enough information, what tests are failing? How are they failing? What is actual and expected output for some test value? Are you sure `Transform::rotate` returns correct rotation matrix?

Comment: I have attached the full implementation of `Transform::rotate` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try if something like this fixes it:

```
glm::mat3 Transform::rotate(float angle, const glm::vec3& axis) {
    glm::mat3 a_x(   0.0f,  axis.z, -axis.y,
                  -axis.z,    0.0f,  axis.x,
                   axis.y, -axis.x,    0.0f);
    angle = glm::radians(angle);
    return glm::mat3() * cos(angle) + sin(angle) * a_x
        + (1.0f - cos(angle)) * glm::outerProduct(axis, axis);
}
```

Comment: This does not work. And instead of rotating smoothly, this turns out to be "jumping".

Comment: @YichengYe I tested this in my program and it seems to rotate my camera correctly. How exactly is it not working (except for "jumping" which probably has completely different cause)? Is it rotating in wrong direction?

Comment: It does rotate in the correct direction but the rotation is not smooth, like rotating for 180 degree per click.

Answer (score 0):

I googled around and find a solution:

```
// Transforms the camera left around the "crystal ball" interface
void Transform::left(float degrees, vec3& eye, vec3& up) {
    // YOUR CODE FOR HW1 HERE
    eye = eye * rotate(degrees, up);
}
```

The rotation function is correct.